# fractional heat equation and spectral method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I want to apply a spectral method for the weak formulation of the equation

$(-\Delta)^su=f$ $s>0$

with zero Dirichlet boundary conditions, where $(-\Delta)^s$ shall be the fractional laplacian on an intervall of the form $(a,b)$.

I assume I have a ONB in $L^2(a,b)$ $\phi_i$ that is an ONS $H^s_0(a,b)$.

Then the weak formulation reads, when $u_N:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \alpha_i\varphi_i$ is the projection of $u$ on $L^2$

$\lambda_i \alpha_i =(f, \varphi_i)_{L^2}$ $(i=1,\ldots, n)$

What basis functions are available whose regularity explicitly depend on the $s$ i.e. only differentiable up to the order $s$ not higher.

Comment: By $H_0^s$ do you apply Dirichlet boundary condition on the equation?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention. With zero Dirichlet boundary condition